# angularjs no effect in ascx page

Tags: angularjs

I have web application with master page and content pages.  Inside content aspx page I am trying to open a model popup user control ascx page using Ajax ModalPopupExtender.

Inside ascx user control trying to bind data from database using AngularJS.

Initially when I open the user control page, table/grid is not displaying any data.

Using Developer tools IE/Crome when I reload the page, next time it shows the data.

I think DOM is not getting updated in the first display, how can I solve this problem.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: Some sample code would be nice.  I don't know but if the html is added it probably isn't being compiled by angular.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, I cannot create plunker with the above scenario. In simple words - inside aspx page open a pop up ascx user control page, using angularjs display data in Ascx.

Comment: Really difficult to provide any help without some type of code examples (either via Plnkr or at least copy/paste some code snippets). Don't have to put the entire code up, but can you put up an example of how you're trying to load the file and explain your general file structure? The above explanation could cover any number of situations, so it's difficult or impossible to help without more information...

Comment: Ok, I will try to give some sample code & elaborate more.